# Unable to fetch excel file in production in nextjs

Tags: next.js, production, static-files, vercel

I have an excel file named `Words.xlsx` in public directory. Initially, during development mode, setting file path to `/public/Words.xlsx` worked fine but it failed in production mode saying that it can't read file path. Then, I read [this](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving) and changed path to`/Words.xlsx` but I am still receiving the same error(below) in my function logs of vercel.

```js
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Words.xlsx'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '/Words.xlsx'
}
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Words.xlsx'
```

Further, I am using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/read-excel-file) npm package to read excel file. Below is the code of how I use it:

`const res1Sheet = await readXlsxFile('/Words.xlsx', { sheet: 1 });`

How do I solve this?

Comment: Is the Excel file present at build time, or is it added at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

Checking documentation, found this. Hopefully it might help someone who comes here one day.
Note: Only assets that are in the public directory at build time will be served by Next.js. Files added at runtime won't be available. We recommend using a third party service like AWS S3 for persistent file storage.

Answer (score 0):

give full path such as **public/Words.xlsx**
Refer this documentation: https://docs.sheetjs.com/docs/demos/content#nextjs

you can use this sysntax:
**const res1Sheet = await readXlsxFile('public/Words.xlsx', { sheet: 1 });**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32792303)